# How to make a radio button in Jquery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, radio-button

How can I make the check box a radio button? I want to add a radio button before `By buffer` and `By polygon`.

[image]

```
dialog1.empty();
var header = $('<h5></h5>').text('By buffer');
var toggleBtn = $('<button><i id="toggle-icon" class="fa fa-circle"></i></button>').attr('id', 'toggle-buffer-btn').attr('class', 'btn btn-default btn-sm');                    
var inputRadius = $('<input type="text"/>').attr('id', 'radius').attr('class', 'btn btn-default btn-sm').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var helpLabel = $('<span id="help-label">Click and drag mouse to create buffer</span>');
var polyBufferChkbx = $('<input type="checkbox">').attr('id', 'polygon-buffer');
var polyBufferLabel = $('<span id="polygon-buffer-label"> &nbsp By polygon</span>');
var val;

dialog1.append(header);
dialog1.append(toggleBtn);
dialog1.append(inputRadius);
dialog1.append(helpLabel);
dialog1.append('<br/>');
dialog1.append('<br/>');
dialog1.append(polyBufferChkbx);
dialog1.append(polyBufferLabel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery UI, why not let it help you.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wfqv3orm/

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog1">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var dialog1 = $("#dialog1");
  dialog1.empty();
  var header = $("<h5>", {
    class: "dialog-header"
  }).text("By buffer").appendTo(dialog1);
  $("<button>", {
    id: "toggle-buffer-btn",
    class: "btn btn-default btn-sm"
  }).appendTo(dialog1);
  dialog1.find("button").append($("<i>", {
    id: "toggle-icon",
    class: "fa fa-circle"
  }));
  $("<input>", {
    type: "text",
    id: "radius",
    class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm'
  }).prop('disabled', true).appendTo(dialog1);
  $("<span>", {
    id: "help-label",
    style: "margin-bottom: 2em;"
  }).html("Click and drag mouse to create buffer").appendTo(dialog1);
  $("<input>", {
    type: "checkbox",
    id: 'polygon-buffer'
  }).appendTo(dialog1);
  $("<label>", {
    id: "polygon-buffer-label",
    for: "polygon-buffer"
  }).html("By polygon").appendTo(dialog1);
  dialog1.controlgroup();
  var val;
});
```

Little bit faster to just build and append elements all at once in my opinion.